# Kendo UI Pie Chart Color in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Please I have the following code

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CellMinistry.CampusMinistry.Models.Domain.Charting_Models.MemberDistributionModel>
@{
    var memberCount = ViewBag.MemberCount is int ? (int) ViewBag.MemberCount : 0;
}

 @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("chart")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .Series(series => series.Pie(
        model => model.Value,
        model => model.Name,
        null,
        null // Color expression is omitted
     ).Labels(c => c.Visible(true).Template("#= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#"))).Title(String.Format("Total Members: {0}", memberCount))

    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0:N0}")
   ))
```

where Model data is from database and dynamically generated.

Anyways, The colors of the generated sections are somewhat alike and I cant find any docmentation as  to how to customize them.

I dont want to include the colors in Model

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use the [seriesColors](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-seriesColors) property.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CellMinistry.CampusMinistry.Models.Domain.Charting_Models.MemberDistributionModel>
@{
    var memberCount = ViewBag.MemberCount is int ? (int) ViewBag.MemberCount : 0;
}

 @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("chart")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .Series(series => series.Pie(
        model => model.Value,
        model => model.Name,
        null,
        null // Color expression is omitted
     ).Labels(c => c.Visible(true).Template("#= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#"))).Title(String.Format("Total Members: {0}", memberCount))
    .SeriesColors("red", "blue", "yellow", "#006634", "#c72e15")
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0:N0}")
   ))
```